# He was so sure that he "has" or "had" scored a home run?

Tags: word-choice, perfect-constructions

Which of the two is correct?

> He was so sure that he **has** scored a home run, but he failed.

Or

> He was so sure that he **had** scored a home run, but he failed.

Answer (score 1):

The latter is the correct sentence.

> He was so sure that he had scored a home run, but he failed.

Just look at the general timeline of the event. It's in the past.

- "He ***was*** so sure..."

The '*was so sure*' indicates that the the subject is talking about a feeling (a feeling of certainty), that he felt a while ago. It may or may not imply the fact that the listener is still feeling the same way, which is irrelevant. But the feeling started a certain time ago (Past).

- "he ***failed***"

He was unsuccessful in whatever he had tried to accomplish, again, a thing *'had tried'* implies something from the past.

So you can generalize that the entire timeline of the event lies in the past.